# How to grab data from multiple different files and add to one dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, csv, conditional-statements

Here is my dataframe

```
# sample of my real data
data = {'RequestCode':[1111, 2222, 8888, 1212, 2222,1010, 1111],
        'Code':['J1', 'J2', 'J8', 'J12', 'J2', 'J10', 'J1'],
        'OrderDate':[20210218, 20210303, 20210303, 20210515, 20210515, 20210218, 20210515]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
    RequestCode Code    OrderDate
0   1111      J1    20210218
1   2222      J2    20210303
2   8888      J8    20210303
3   1212      J12   20210515
4   2222      J2    20210515
5   1010      J10   20210218
6   1111      J1    20210515
```

I also have a folder with tens of csv files, however all have the same structure.
they all named as file{date}.csv
each made of four coulmns [Date, Code, Cost, Number]

For example  "file20210303.csv" looks like this

| Date | Code | Cost | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20200512 | 8888 | 500 | 32581 |
| 20200803 | 2222 | 1500 | 21669 |
| 20210501 | 1313 | 2000 | 5679 |

and  "file20210218.csv" looks like this

| Date | Code | Cost | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20210512 | 1111 | 1500 | 66581 |
| 18200803 | 3333 | 1500 | 21669 |
| 20210501 | 1010 | 2000 | 5679 |

Now I want to take the Number(the forth column) of each .csv file which the {date} in its filename is the same as dataframe "OrderDate" and the "RequestCode" is the same as "Code" in the csv

so basically add a new column as Number to my dataframe

```
df
    RequestCode Code    OrderDate   Number
0   1111      J1    20210218       66581
1   2222      J2    20210303       21669
2   8888      J8    20210303       32581
3   1212      J12   20210515
4   2222      J2    20210515   
5   1010      J10   20210218       5679
6   1111      J1    20210515
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use pd.merge

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file20210303.csv')
df = pd.merge(df, df1, how = 'left', left_on =['RequestCode', 'OrderDate'], right_on =['Code','Date'])
df = df.drop(['Cost'], axis=1)
```

Comment: @Andew Your suggestion works when there is only one csv file! I have to grab data from all the csv files which their date is comparable to my dates in df['OrderDate']

Comment: simple, repeat the code with the next file.